# Funciones definidas con #define

Tags: c, funcion, define

Estoy intentando modificar un código de iPXE para bootear sistemas por red. El problema que me encuentro es que hay una función que está implementada la cuál permite obtener el valor de un GPIO del exterior y tirando del hilo entre las funciones que hay me encuentro que hay definida una función en una instrucción `#define` y nunca había trabajado con código de esta manera.

**El código exacto es el siguiente:**

1. Aquí quiero saber lo que hace la función `uart_readb`.

`ret = uart_readb(UART_BASE + UART_MSR);`

2. Voy a buscar la implementación de la función, y me encuentro con lo siguiente:

`#define uart_readb(addr) inb((addr))`

Aquí es donde empiezo a patinar, porque nunca he visto una declaración de una función con esta sintaxis. No sé qué valores hacen referencia a la entrada, cuáles a la salida, etc. Me decido ir a ver si consigo más información a través de la función `inb`...

3. Buscando cómo se implementa la función `inb` me encuentro lo siguiente en un `.h`

`uint8_t inb ( volatile uint8_t *io_addr );`, cuya descripción es *Read byte from I/O-mapped device*, y los parámetros los define como: *@io_addr = I/O address* y *@ret data = Value read*, por lo que intuyo que esta función accede a la posición de memoria dada por `io_addr` y retorna el valor del byte leído.

Con la información del punto 3, me da que pensar que la función `uart_readb` lee **un byte** de la dirección de memoria pasada por `addr`. ¿Es esto correcto?

Y otra cosa más... La función `inb` dice que retorna **un byte**, y hago hincapié en esto, porque el valor devuelto por `uart_readb` (ret), luego realiza una `AND` con un 0x10, por lo que estaríamos hablando de que sólo nos interesaría el primer bit del "segundo byte" cuando estamos supuestamente trabajando únicamente con el "primer byte", ya que las funciones anteriores sólo retornaban **un byte**.

Sé que es un jaleo todo lo que he puesto aquí, así que si tenéis dudas al respecto decídmelo y edito la pregunta las veces que sea necesario.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Son dos preguntas, así que vamos por partes

### Qué hace `#define`

Primero aclarar que no está definiendo una función. Lo que se define se denomina técnicamente una *macro*, y no es más que un reemplazo de texto.

Simplemente define una cadena para que sea reemplazada por otra. Antes siquiera de que el compilador "entre" a ver el código se ejecuta el *preprocesador*, y ese preprocesador es el que se ocupa de reemplazar las cadenas definidas por `#define`, entre otras cosas (también el preprocesador se ocupa de reemplazar los `#include` por los contenidos del fichero que se indique, etc.)

Al final el código que ve el compilador no es el que tú has escrito, sino el que resulta del paso previo del *preprocesador*.

En este caso `#define uart_readb(addr) inb((addr))` viene a decirle al preprocesador "cada vez que veas en el código fuente la cadena `uart_readb` seguida de algo entre paréntesis, reemplázalo por `inb((ese algo))`" Esto se llama "expandir la macro".

Así que si tu código tiene una línea que dice por ejemplo `uart_readb(p_dir)`, el preprocesador transformará esa cadena en otra que dice `inb((p_dir))` y eso será lo que compilará el compilador.

> **Nota al pie**. Lo de añadir paréntesis extra alrededor es una precaución típica por si acaso lo que va dentro de ellos es una expresión compleja, para garantizar el orden de evaluación, pues el preprocesador es "tonto" y no sabe nada de expresiones, prececendia o tipos, solo reemplaza cadenas. Considera este ejemplo: `#define multiplicar(a,b) a*b`.  Te encontrarías con que no funciona correctamente si en el código escribes `multiplicar(2+2, 5)`, pues para el preprocesador `a` sería simplemente la cadena `2+2` y `b` sería `5`, por lo que el resultado del preprocesador cambiaría `multiplicar(2+2,5)` por `2+2*5` que no es lo mismo que `(2+2)*5`.
>
> Por ello, para evitar sorpresas como esta, siempre se suelen poner paréntesis alrededor de los parámetros en el texto de sustitución de la macro. Es decir, se definiría `#define multiplicar(a,b) (a)*(b)`

No hay más misterio. De hecho tú mismo podrías el "buscar y reemplazar" del editor para hacer esos cambios y el resultado sería exactamente el mismo, pues el compilador vería lo mismo.

La razón por la que se usa `#define` para estas cosas es típicamente para proporcionar diferentes implementaciones según el operativo o la plataforma,  si se combina con directivas como `#ifdef` etc. (que también son para el preprocesador)

Así que habías deducido correctamente que en el fondo se llama a `inb()`

### Lo del byte

Dices que se retorna un byte pero después no entiendes por qué se hace `& 0x10` ya que dices que esto indicaría que se tienen dos bytes.

En este punto te equivocas. Las representaciones en hexadecimal usan un dígito por cada 4 bits (ya que con 4 bits se pueden representar números entre 0 y 15, o F). Así que la cantidad hexadecimal 0x10 representa a la cantidad binaria `00010000` que como ves son 8 bits y por tanto un byte.

El bit que se está aislando a través de ese AND es el bit en posición 4 (numerando desde la derecha siendo el primer bit el de posición 0). También puede decirse que es el bit más bajo del *nibble* más alto dentro de ese byte (un *nibble* es un grupo de 4 bits).

Comment: Lo primero agradecerte tu respuesta, como siempre son un bálsamo de sabiduría. Por lo tanto, teniendo `uart_readb`, yo ahora lo debería de tomar como que se llama a `inb`, y según la explicación comentada en el código, se accede a la dirección de memoria marcada por `io_addr`, que es el mismo parámetro `addr` que se pasa a la función `uart_readb`. Al final se retorna el byte que existe en esa posición de memoria y a correr, ¿no?

Comment: Sí, eso es. He añadido una nota a la respuesta, aunque no preguntaste por ella, para aclarar por qué el doble paréntesis en la expansión de la macro.

Comment: Perfecto @abufalia, muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda ;)